# Down loading 70 k research papers information from the web of science ( WOS)

Tags: python, csv, web, text, classification

I'm currently working on text classification, but I'm facing a challenge with downloading information for a query that involves around 70k research papers. Unfortunately, I'm having persistent connectivity issues with the Web of Science website. potential solutions to this problem.

#### query:

`higher education (Publication Titles) OR higher education (Title) OR higher education (Topic) OR higher education (Abstract) and Article (Document Types) and Education Educational Research (Web of Science Categories) and Education Educational Research (Web of Science Categories) and English (Languages) and Social Sciences Citation Index (SSCI) or Emerging Sources Citation Index (ESCI) (Web of Science Index)`

```
from wos import WosClient

# create a WOS client
wos_client = WosClient()

# connect to the WOS server
wos_client.connect()

# define the query
query_string = 'higher education (Publication Titles) OR higher education (Title) OR higher education (Topic) OR higher education (Abstract) and Article (Document Types) and Education Educational Research (Web of Science Categories) and Education Educational Research (Web of Science Categories) and English (Languages) and Social Sciences Citation Index (SSCI) or Emerging Sources Citation Index (ESCI) (Web of Science Index)'

# query WOS
result_set = wos_client.search(query_string, count=7000)

# print the results
for record in result_set:
    print(record)
```

After running the Python code, I encountered an error that reads

> 'suds.WebFault: b"Server raised fault: 'No matches returned for IP `91.106.56.60`'"'.

I'm unsure of what this error means or how to resolve it.

Comment: https://wos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#faq-i-cannot-connect I’m not sure if that’s the Python module you’re using, but the error looks the same. I don’t see you supplying credentials in your WosClient() constructor like the docs show. Do you need that, premium access?